# How do you set the state and status of an email object using a SOAP call?

Tags: soap, dynamics-crm-4

I am really struggling to solve this.  I have trawled the web and found some examples of how to set the state and status of an object, but none of them seem to work for me.

Does anyone have some example of how the soap envelope should look and what the properties of the Msxml2.XMLHTTP object should be for a synchronous call to the web service?

Thanks in advance,
Gray

EDIT

Ok ... so for an unexplained reason I got a downvote on this, and no answer, so I thought I would describe what I have currently got, and what I am getting.

This is the main function (pretty much lifted from one of the examples I found:

```
 function setStateCodeForEntity(entityName, entityId, stateOptionsetValue, statusOptionsetValue) {


    var request = "<s:Envelope xmlns:s=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">";
    request += "<s:Body>";
    request += "<Execute xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts/Services\" xmlns:i=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\">";
    request += "<request i:type=\"b:SetStateRequest\" xmlns:a=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts\" xmlns:b=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/crm/2011/Contracts\">";
    request += "<a:Parameters xmlns:c=\"http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic\">";
    request += "<a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>";
    request += "<c:key>EntityMoniker</c:key>";
    request += "<c:value i:type=\"a:EntityReference\">";
    request += "<a:Id>" + entityId + "</a:Id>";
    request += "<a:LogicalName>" + entityName + "</a:LogicalName>";
    request += "<a:Name i:nil=\"true\" />";
    request += "</c:value>";
    request += "</a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>";
    request += "<a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>";
    request += "<c:key>State</c:key>";
    request += "<c:value i:type=\"a:OptionSetValue\">";
    request += "<a:Value>"+stateOptionsetValue+"</a:Value>";
    request += "</c:value>";
    request += "</a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>";
    request += "<a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>";
    request += "<c:key>Status</c:key>";
    request += "<c:value i:type=\"a:OptionSetValue\">";
    request += "<a:Value>"+statusOptionsetValue+"</a:Value>";
    request += "</c:value>";
    request += "</a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>";
    request += "</a:Parameters>";
    request += "<a:RequestId i:nil=\"true\" />";
    request += "<a:RequestName>SetState</a:RequestName>";
    request += "</request>";
    request += "</Execute>";
    request += "</s:Body>";
    request += "</s:Envelope>";

var ret = executeSoapRequest("execute", request);
```

}

The executeSoapRequest function looks like this:

```
function executeSoapRequest(action, xml) {
var actionUrl = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/crm/2007/WebServices/" + action;

var xmlHttpRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
xmlHttpRequest.Open("POST", "/mscrmservices/2007/CrmService.asmx", false);
xmlHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("SOAPAction", actionUrl);
xmlHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8");
xmlHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-Length", xml.length);
xmlHttpRequest.send(xml);

return xmlHttpRequest.responseXML;
```

}

and I have tried calling the method described at the top with the calls (note that newGuid is assigned somewhere else, and contains the Guid of a new email record that I wish to set the state/status for):

```
setStateCodeForEntity("email", newGuid, 1, 2);
```

and

```
setStateCodeForEntity("email", newGuid, "Completed", 2);
```

What I am getting is a Server 500 error, with the following response:

```
"<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd\">\r\n<html xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\">\r\n<head>\r\n<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\"/>\r\n<title>500 - Internal server error.</title>\r\n<style type=\"text/css\">\r\n<!--\r\nbody{margin:0;font-size:.7em;font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;background:#EEEEEE;}\r\nfieldset{padding:0 15px 10px 15px;} \r\nh1{font-size:2.4em;margin:0;color:#FFF;}\r\nh2{font-size:1.7em;margin:0;color:#CC0000;} \r\nh3{font-size:1.2em;margin:10px 0 0 0;color:#000000;} \r\n#header{width:96%;margin:0 0 0 0;padding:6px 2% 6px 2%;font-family:\"trebuchet MS\", Verdana, sans-serif;color:#FFF;\r\nbackground-color:#555555;}\r\n#content{margin:0 0 0 2%;position:relative;}\r\n.content-container{background:#FFF;width:96%;margin-top:8px;padding:10px;position:relative;}\r\n-->\r\n</style>\r\n</head>\r\n<body>\r\n<div id=\"header\"><h1>Server Error</h1></div>\r\n<div id=\"content\">\r\n <div class=\"content-container\"><fieldset>\r\n  <h2>500 - Internal server error.</h2>\r\n  <h3>There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.</h3>\r\n </fieldset></div>\r\n</div>\r\n</body>\r\n</html>\r\n<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\"><soap:Body><soap:Fault><faultcode>Server</faultcode><faultstring>Object reference not set to an instance of an object.</faultstring><detail><error xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\"><displaytitle /><displaytext /><description>Object reference not set to an instance of an object.</description><file>Not available</file><line>Not available</line><details>Not available</details><requesturl>http://[SERVERNAME]/mscrmservices/2007/CrmService.asmx</requesturl><pathAndQuery>/mscrmservices/2007/CrmService.asmx</pathAndQuery><source>SOAP</source><stacktrace /></error></detail></soap:Fault></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>"
```

HOWEVER ...

I have just noticed that I get a very similar responseText when I use the executeSoapRequest method that does succeed.  When I make the call as described above the status of the email entity is not changed.

I am almost certainly doing something silly, but I have no idea what.  Any constructive help would be a life saver at this time.

Gray

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok ... for completeness, here is the answer:

The main function looks like this:

```
function setStateCodeForEntity(entityName, entityId, stateOptionsetValue, statusOptionsetValue) {

    var request = [
        "<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'>",
        GenerateAuthenticationHeader(),
        "<soap:Body>",
        "<Execute xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/crm/2007/WebServices'>", 
        "<Request xsi:type='SetStateDynamicEntityRequest'>",
        "<Entity>",
        "<Name xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/crm/2006/CoreTypes'>", entityName, "</Name>",
        "<Id xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/crm/2006/CoreTypes'>", entityId, "</Id>",
        "</Entity>",
        "<State>", stateOptionsetValue, "</State>",
        "<Status>", statusOptionsetValue, "</Status>",
        "</Request>",
        "</Execute>",
        "</soap:Body>",
        "</soap:Envelope>"
        ].join("");

        var ret = executeSoapRequest("Execute", request);
 }
```

Notice the Request type is 'SetStateDynamicEntityRequest', which seemed to be the main problem with my original attempt, but also this version is far more simple that I was originally using.

The method is called by

```
setStateCodeForEntity("email", newGuid, 'Completed', 2);
```

I was given the answer by a colleague who recommended the Crm Service Toolkit (http://crmtoolkit.codeplex.com/) and the code was pretty much lifted from there.  Further information at http://danielcai.blogspot.co.uk/2010/07/crm-web-service-toolkit-for-javascript.html